# How to create a dynamic pivot table SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, pivot-table

That is what I have in my SQL Server 2008 database, I am trying pivot table but having hard time to get it to work

```
Username     Date     hours
--------------------------------------
John       Feb 1995    45
John       Feb 1995    16      
Nancy      March 1998  25
John       May 2001   35.5
Peter      Feb 1995    46
Bill       May 2001    48
Bill       Feb 1995    56
```

I need to get this result:

```
UserName   Feb 1995   March 1998   May 2001
--------   --------   ----------   ---------
John        61                      35.5
Nancy                    25
Peter       46
Bill        56                      48
--------------------------------------------
Total       163          25         83.5
```

Basically I need take all the values from the date column values (1995-10-01) and make it the title of the columns, this is dynamic depends on how many values in the table.

Any help is well appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a way to do it:

```
create table #tab (
            Username nvarchar(100),
            [Date] date,
            [hours] numeric(8,1)
        )

insert #tab values 
    ('John', '1995-02-01', 45),
    ('John', '1995-02-01', 16),
    ('Nancy', '1998-03-01', 25),
    ('John', '2001-05-01', 35.5),
    ('Peter', '1995-02-01', 46),
    ('Bill', '2001-05-01', 48),
    ('Bill', '1995-02-01', 56)


select  pvt.*
    from (
        select  Username, 
                datename(month, [Date]) + ' ' + convert(nvarchar(20), datepart(year, [Date])) [Date], 
                [hours] 
            from #tab
        ) t
    pivot (
        SUM([hours])
        for [Date] in ([February 1995], [March 1998], [May 2001])
        ) pvt

drop table #tab
```

Now, the way you'll probably need to do it:

```
create table #tab (
            Username nvarchar(100),
            [Date] date,
            [hours] numeric(8,1)
        )

insert #tab values 
    ('John', '1995-02-01', 45),
    ('John', '1995-02-01', 16),
    ('Nancy', '1998-03-01', 25),
    ('John', '2001-05-01', 35.5),
    ('Peter', '1995-02-01', 46),
    ('Bill', '2001-05-01', 48),
    ('Bill', '1995-02-01', 56)

declare @columns nvarchar(max) = ''
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''
declare @delim nvarchar(10) = ''

select  @columns = @columns + @delim + '[' + x.[Date] + ']',
        @delim = ', '
    from (  
        select  datename(month, t.[Date]) + ' ' + convert(nvarchar(20), datepart(year, t.[Date])) [Date],
                datepart(year, t.[Date]) [Year],
                datepart(month, t.[Date]) [Month]
            from #tab t
        ) x
    group by x.[Date]
    order by MAX(x.[Year]), MAX(x.[Month])


select @columns

set @sql = '
    select  pvt.Username,
            ' + @columns + '
        from (
            select  Username, 
                    datename(month, [Date]) + '' '' + convert(nvarchar(20), datepart(year, [Date])) [Date], 
                    [hours] 
                from #tab
            ) t
        pivot (
            SUM([hours])
            for [Date] in (' + @columns + ')
            ) pvt
    '

exec(@sql)

drop table #tab
```

The problem is that PIVOT doesn't allow you to dynamically specify the resulting columns... you have to know what's in the column you're pivoting on to do it.  The solution is to create dynamic SQL with the distinct columns, and then build a pivot statement based on that.

Comment: Thanks Chris, your solution worked, the only change I made was instread of creating the table, I used SELECT into #tab from the existing table. all worked well.. now I need to know how to add each column for every month in the Pivot Table

Comment: I am trying to order the columns by Year, but its not working, thats what I am getting : [April 2011], [December 2010], [February 2011], [January 2011], [January 2015], [March 2011], [October 2011], [September 2011]

Comment: Sorry for the delay, Stack Overflow had some trouble last week, and I couldn't upload the change.  I modified the part that generates the column order to sort by year/month, so it should be in order now.

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks a lot your update fixed the Date sorting issue, many thanks