# SQL Statement Extract XML

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm trying to extract XML column into different columns. I need to figure out how to do this in SQL statement.

Here is one record presented from "ItemSpecifics" column:
"ItemsSpecifics"  already stored in sql database Table "ItemEbayID" as xml field
and I'm trying to split this column.

```
<SelectedValues haveDefaultsBeenSet="true">
  <SelectedValue>
    <Name>Consignment Status</Name>
    <Value>False</Value>
  </SelectedValue>
  <SelectedValue>
    <Name>Salesperson</Name>
    <Value>'Vasya'</Value>
  </SelectedValue>
  <SelectedValue>
    <Name>Model</Name>
    <Value />
  </SelectedValue>
  <SelectedValue>
    <Name>Salesperson Paid</Name>
    <Value>False</Value>
  </SelectedValue>
  <SelectedValue>
    <Name>Resolved</Name>
    <Value>False</Value>
  </SelectedValue>
  <SelectedValue>
    <Name>Quality Issue</Name>
    <Value>'None'</Value>
  </SelectedValue>     
</SelectedValues>
```

I looked at many example but none of the could be applied to this xml field.

Comment: How do you want to represent the data?

Comment: Query with output for all these columns: Consignment Status, Salesperson, Model, Salesperson Paid, Resolved, Quality Issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @xml xml = '<SelectedValues>
      <SelectedValue>
        <Name>Consignment Status</Name>
        <Value>False</Value>
      </SelectedValue>
      <SelectedValue>
        <Name>Salesperson</Name>
        <Value>''Vasya''</Value>
      </SelectedValue>
      <SelectedValue>
        <Name>Model</Name>
        <Value />
      </SelectedValue>
      <SelectedValue>
        <Name>Salesperson Paid</Name>
        <Value>False</Value>
      </SelectedValue>
      <SelectedValue>
        <Name>Resolved</Name>
        <Value>False</Value>
      </SelectedValue>
      <SelectedValue>
        <Name>Quality Issue</Name>
        <Value>''None''</Value>
      </SelectedValue>     
    </SelectedValues>'

    select t.c.value('Name[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'),  
           t.c.value('Value[1]', 'nvarchar(500)')
        from @xml.nodes('//SelectedValue') t(c)
```

Comment: Please show me how to extract at least two columns: For exmaple these two columns "Consignment Status", "Salesperson", one is a string the other one is Boolean.

Comment: I tried and it works pretty good. It does split the columns, but how do I declare a column instead just one field.

Comment: To create multiple columns, you'd have to then PIVOT the results.  To do that, it matters if the columns are known ahead of time... if not, you'll need to build dynamic sql to pivot.  Here's a link to that kind of stuff: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29403519/how-to-create-a-dynamic-pivot-table-sql-server-2008/29403771#29403771